# Knockout js values not binded

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I have my code as follows:

**Html:**

```
<select 
    name="data3"
    size="1" 
    id="data3"
    data-bind="options: datalist, value: profile().dat.data()[2].Value()">
</select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function()
{
    clientviewmodel = viewmodel();
    ko.applyBindings(clientviewmodel);
});

function viewmodel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.profile = ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS($.parseJSON(datareceived)));
}
```

**Json:**

```
{ "dat": {"data": [{"Value":"1"}, {"Value":"2"}, {"Value":"3"} ] } }
```

**My problem is, value is not binded on changing the select control.**

Comment: is this the correct json string that you are using?

Comment: Do you have any error is your brower javascript console?

Comment: @Tim B James sorry, like this,  { "dat": {"data": [{"Value":"1"}, {"Value":"2"}, {"Value":"3"} ] } }

Comment: @nemesv I didn't get any error in console.

Comment: @Dani update your question with the correct Json :)

Comment: @TimBJames I edited the question, the Json

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra set of `()` at the end of your binding.

The correct binding should look like:

```
<select 
    name="data3"
    size="1" 
    id="data3"
    data-bind="options: datalist, value: profile().dat.data()[2].Value">
</select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EbadW/1/).

With writing `Value()` you are not binding to your observable property itself but to its underlying value which makes your binding one-way.

Comment: Then please try to repro this in a jsfiddle, you can start with the one what've linked. Because if you don't have any errors in the console writing `profile().dat.data()[2].Value` should fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've written `viewmodel()` as a "classical" constructor but you don't instantiate it with `new`, you're actually setting `profile` as a global variable and not returning anything when you call it and therefore not actually applying bindings to your VM.

Standard JavaScript practice is that names of classical constructors, and only those names, should start with a capital letter to remind you that you need to instantiate them with `new`.

nemesv's and Neil Thomspson's observations also apply; you shouldn't be unwrapping `value` in your binding, and `datalist` needs to be a property of your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Your profile JSON is invalid.

you have

```
{
    "dat"{
        "data"[
            {
                "Value": "1"
            },
            {
                "Value": "2"
            },
            {
                "Value": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

it should be:

```
{
    "dat": {
        "data": [
            {
                "Value": "1"
            },
            {
                "Value": "2"
            },
            {
                "Value": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[JsonLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) is a useful tool in these cases

Comment: I have it like this,     { "dat": {"data": [{"Value":"1"}, {"Value":"2"}, {"Value":"3"} ] } }     value is not binded yet

Comment: datalist is not defined anywhere?